# Disable refreshRememberToken in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

In laravel 5.2 when I do \Auth::logout() there is a `refreshRememberToken` call that tries to regenerate a token (to be saved in database).

Question: **How can I disable this feature?**

I do not want this feature (it generates a lot of error now due the lack of the column & etc)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no configurable way of doing this. (I am not sure, just casted an eye on the code.)

However you can extend&override the logout method of Guard and don't call the refreshRememberToken method (or extend&override refreshRememberToken method and just return true from refreshRememberToken)

If you don't want to extend guard, you can also create a customised user provider which will implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider`.

In the interface you must implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider` there are two method signatures you should bypass:

```
/**
 * Retrieve a user by their unique identifier and "remember me" token.
 *
 * @param  mixed   $identifier
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
 */
public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token);

/**
 * Update the "remember me" token for the given user in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token);
```

After bypassing; you have extend auth `Auth::provider('customimplementation')` and then change the `driver` key of the auth configuration:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'customimplementation',
    ],
],
```

If you need more information about extending auth drivers or guard, follow 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#adding-custom-guards
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers

Answer (score 1):

For now I used the following dirty trick:

On `User` model I added this method

```
function setRememberTokenAttribute($value)
{
    return;
}
```

This looks to me to be more an work-around and not a solution

Comment: I think that is not your fault. This is a debate about 'Interface segregation principle'. I always feel that these method signatures are misplaced (as a user of LTS version). Should all the implementations of UserProvider really have these methods? If I create custom implementations of both Guard and UserProvider, it looks like these methods will no longer be required. If so, why should I implement them?